# Using python Gurobi optimizer to schedule events evenly in time

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I'd like to schedule events to happen as uniformly as possible given some constraints. Here's an example that seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
# 100 potential time slots
times = np.arange(100)
m = gp.Model("try_sched")

schedule_1 = m.addMVar(times.size, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="schedule_1")

mask1 = np.zeros(times.size)

# Set some random times that can't be used
np.random.seed(42)
mask1[np.round(np.random.uniform(low=0,high=99, size=20)).astype(int)] = 1
m.addConstr(schedule_1 @ mask1 == 0)

# Limit the total number of times it can be scheduled
n_limit_1 = 30
m.addConstr(schedule_1.sum() == n_limit_1)

# I events distributed as uniformly as possible. So, minimize chi^2
# for the difference between the cumulative distribution and an ideal cumulative
desired_cumulative_1 = np.round(times/times.max() * n_limit_1)

cumulative_sched_1 = m.addMVar(times.size, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)
cumulative_diff_1 = m.addMVar(times.size, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=-n_limit_1, ub=n_limit_1)

m.addConstr(cumulative_sched_1[0] == schedule_1[0])

for i in np.arange(1,times.size):
    m.addConstr(cumulative_sched_1[i] == cumulative_sched_1[i-1]+schedule_1[i])
    m.addConstr(cumulative_diff_1[i] == cumulative_sched_1[i] - desired_cumulative_1[i])
   
m.setObjective(cumulative_diff_1 @ cumulative_diff_1, GRB.MINIMIZE)
m.optimize()
```

And the results look good:

```
schedule_1.X
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -0.,  1.,  0., -0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,  1.,
   -0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -0.,  0.,  1., -0.,  0.,  1., -0., -0.,  1.,
   -0., -0.,  1.,  0.,  0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,  1., -0.,  0.,  1.,
   -0., -0., -0.,  1.,  0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,  0.,
    0.,  1., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,  1.,  0.,  0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,
    1., -0., -0.,  1., -0.,  0.,  1.,  0., -0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,
    1., -0., -0.,  1.,  0., -0., -0.,  1.,  0., -0.,  1., -0., -0.,
    1., -0., -0.,  0.,  1.,  0., -0.,  1., -0.])
```

This seems to work pretty well. My issue is I'd now like to schedule additional events (also optimized to be uniform, and constrained so events cannot be in the same time slot), but my objective is quadratic, so I can't set multiple objectives.

Is there a better way to define "uniform in time" that is linear so I can set multiple objectives?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe use absolute values instead of quadratic deviations. This is like LAD regression. This can be formulated in a linear fashion.